# How to run one command on multiple terminals?

Tags: python, shell, terminal, command, conemu

I am using ConEmu windows emulator and I would like to run one simple command on more terminals at the same time. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: tmux can synchronize panes.

Comment: ConEmu can do that internally. Third-party software is not required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apps+G groups input for all visible panes.

Comment: Thank you very much :) and can I enter some command for all opened tabs?

Comment: No. You can't even see them. That applies to visible tab only.